# Could not see custom web part under SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to add web part under pagelayout. So I clicked on "WebPart" menu under ribbon control. Under this i can not see my web part. Feature is activate and web parts gallary also have web parts.

Earlier this was working fine but now I can not see my custom web parts.

[image]

Comment: Was the permission for the webparts changed on your webpart gallery?

Comment: Can you please let me know how can i see this?

Answer (score 0):

Cant put it in comment so Ill put the image here

Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Under Galleries (Web Parts) -> Then you will see a webpart list, hit edit then this window will pop up.

Just make sure you are on the top level site

[image]